# Rellenar array sin número repetidos

Tags: java, array, random

El ejercicio es el siguiente:
Supongamos que encontramos una bolsa con las piezas de un puzzle, sabemos que están todas menos una.
Diseña un programa Java que nos diga qué pieza falta.
Se leerá por teclado el número de piezas totales que tiene el puzle, como mínimo 3.
Se debe implementar la bolsa de piezas que será un vector y se llenará de manera aleatoria. Los números no pueden ser repetidos.
La longitud de la bolsa será de una unidad menos que el número de piezas totales del puzzle.

Mi problema es que no se como hacer para que al rellenar el array los números no esten repetidos, adjunto lo que llevo:

Una cosa mas, debe ser realizado con estructuras básicas ya que estoy empezando y no me dejan utilizar ningun metodo ni clases aun no vistas

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int verificador=0;
    
    while(verificador==0) {
    
        Scanner N=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introducir número de piezas totales del puzzle (N>=3): ");
        int piezas=N.nextInt();
        
        int [] bolsa=new int[piezas-1];
        
        if(piezas>=3) {
            
            for(int i=0;i<piezas-1;i++) {
                bolsa[i]=(int)(Math.random()*piezas+1);
                System.out.print(bolsa[i]+" ");
                
                if(bolsa [0-i-1]==bolsa[i]) {
                    
                }
            }
            
            verificador++;
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Los array tienen esta forma `array[index]=valor`. Entonces creas un array de bool donde `true` indica si el valor está en la bolsa y `false` en caso contrario. Siendo `index` el número de la pieza

Comment: vale, pero en el caso de que sea true como hago para decirle que ese numero no me lo tenga en cuenta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {      
  Scanner N = new Scanner( System.in );
  System.out.println( "Introducir número de piezas totales del puzzle (N>=3): " );
  int totalPiezas = N.nextInt();
  if( totalPiezas >= 3 ) {
     int piezasExistentes = totalPiezas -1; 
     int[] bolsa = new int[ piezasExistentes ];
     int control[] = new int[ totalPiezas ];         
     for( int i = 0; i < piezasExistentes; i++ ) {
        int aux = numeroValido( bolsa, totalPiezas, i );
        bolsa[ i ] = aux;
        control[ aux -1 ] = 1;
     }
     for( int ii = 0; ii < control.length; ii++ ) {
        if( control[ ii ] == 0 ) {
           System.out.println( "falta la pieza " + ( ii + 1 ) );               
        }
     }
  }
}

static int numeroValido( int bolsa[], int totalPiezas, int xx ) {  
   int ran = (int) ( Math.random() * totalPiezas +1 );
   for( int i = 0; i < xx; i++ ) {
      if( bolsa[ i ] == ran ) {
         return numeroValido( bolsa, totalPiezas, xx );
      }
   }
   return ran;
}
```

Bueno, una primera aproximación, creo que se puede hacer algo más elegante para devolver el valor que falta... pero no se me ha ocurrido nada.

El primer **for**, itera sobre **bolsa**, llama al método **numeroValido**, y asigna la salida de este a la posición de **bolsa** sobre la que está iterando y se asigna a la posición de **control** que coincide con el número aleatorio **1**.

El método **numerovalido**, genera un numero aleatorio, y comprueba si este se encuentra dentro de **bolsa**, si no está, lo devuelve, y si está, se llama a si mismo (recursión).

Por último recorremos el array **control** y aquella posición que contenga un **0**, será el valor faltante.

Pensando que tal vez no te sea permitido usar recursión, agregué otra forma de conseguir lo que te piden:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  Scanner N = new Scanner( System.in );
  System.out.println( "Introducir número de piezas totales del puzzle (N>=3): " );
  int totalPiezas = N.nextInt();
  if( totalPiezas >= 3 ) {
     int piezasExistentes = totalPiezas -1; 
     int[] bolsa = new int[ piezasExistentes ];
     int control[] = new int[ totalPiezas ];         
     for( int i = 0; i < piezasExistentes; i++ ) {
        int ran = (int) ( Math.random() * totalPiezas +1 );
        for( int k = 0; true; k++ ) {               
           if( numeroValido( bolsa, ran, i ) ) {
              break;
           }   
           ran = (int) ( Math.random() * totalPiezas +1 );
        }
        bolsa[ i ] = ran;
        control[ ran -1 ] = 1;
     }
     for( int ii = 0; ii < control.length; ii++ ) {
        if( control[ ii ] == 0 ) {
           System.out.println( "falta la pieza " + ( ii + 1 ) );               
        }
     }
  h.v( bolsa );
  }
}   

static boolean numeroValido( int bolsa[], int ran, int xx ) {      
   for( int i = 0; i < xx; i++ ) {
      if( bolsa[ i ] == ran ) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: gracias, lo unico que no entiendo es para que sirve salida, del segundo if, el programa no me lo reconoce y lo cambio a bolsa [k] pero el primer digito del array se me repite

Comment: @AlvaroMoron, mil perdones, cuando hice la función, usa salida como array, luego para publicar la repuesta lo cambié por bolsa... pero se me pasó una, ya edito la respuesta, gracias por la observación.

Comment: @AlvaroMoron, ahora si... la falla que tenía no la entiendo, de hecho voy a abrir una pregunta con eso, si el bloque **if** detectaba una igualdad, yo reseteaba la variable **k** a cero para que siguiera iterando... no entiendo porque, pero la primera iteración, no pasaba por el if... probe de asignarle a **k = -1**, pero me salia un error (es lógico, el array no tiene posición -1).. en fin, me replantee todo el ejercicio, y salió más limpio (creo).

Comment: El error era esporádico, ya que se tenía que dar que la repetición ocurriera en la primera vez, por eso no lo detecte.

Answer (score 2):

Esta solución es de complejidad O(n). Más sencilla de entender. Explicación en comentarios:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    arregloAleatorio(10);
}

public static void arregloAleatorio(int bolsa) {
    Random random = new Random();

    // se llena la bolsa completa con piezas desde 1 hasta el total de la bolsa
    int bolsaCompleta[] = new int[bolsa];
    for (int i = 0; i < bolsaCompleta.length; i++) {
        bolsaCompleta[i] = i + 1;
    }

    // se desordena el arreglo haciendo intercambios aleatorios
    for (int i = 0; i < bolsaCompleta.length; i++) {
        int temp = bolsaCompleta[i];
        int randomIndex = random.nextInt(bolsaCompleta.length);
        bolsaCompleta[i] = bolsaCompleta[randomIndex];
        bolsaCompleta[randomIndex] = temp;
    }

    // se crea una bolsa incompleta la cual tiene una longitud menor en una unidad
    int bolsaIncompleta[] = new int[bolsaCompleta.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < bolsaIncompleta.length; i++) {
        bolsaIncompleta[i] = bolsaCompleta[i];
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bolsaIncompleta));

    // la pieza faltante siempre estará en la última posición
    System.out.println("Pieza que falta: " + bolsaCompleta[bolsaCompleta.length - 1]);
}
```

}

Comment: confieso que no creí que funcionara, lo probé, y solo puedo sacarme el sombrero ante su maravilloso enfoque, va mi voto.

Answer (score 0):

Observando tu código, entiendo que deseas llenar una matriz de números aleatorios enteros que no se repitan. Estos números además, parecen ser generados de forma aleatoria en un rango con un mínimo de 1 y un máximo de la cantidad de piezas.

Podría recomendarte diversas formas para solucionar tu problema, como por ejemplo el uso de [`HashSet<T>`](https://ifgeekthen.nttdata.com/es/que-es-hashset-java-y-como-comenzar-con-el). No obstante, comentas que no se te permite emplezar soluciones elaboradas, métodos ni utilidades, y te conviene una solución lo más básica posible. Acredito a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61595029/9443618) de **Lokesh Sharma**, por proporcionar la solución que escogí para generar un entero aleatorio en un rango y, te propongo mi solución ante esas limitantes:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int   piezas  = 25;
    int[] bolsa   = new int[piezas];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < piezas - 1; i++)
    {
        int     minimo      = 1;
        int     maximo      = piezas;
        int     rango       = maximo - minimo + 1;
        int     aleatorio   = (int)(Math.random() * rango) + minimo;
        boolean existe      = false;
        
        for(int j = 0; j < bolsa.length; j++)
        {
            if (bolsa[j] == aleatorio)
            {
                existe = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if (! existe)
        {
            bolsa[i] = aleatorio;   
        }
    }
}
```

Se trata de emplear dos bucles `for`, el primero para agregar y segundo para verificar si tu bolsa ya contiene el elemento que intentas agregar. Con esto, empleas una variable de control que indica si el segundo bucle encontró una coincidencia, y de no ser así procede a agregar el elemento.

Este código no es exactamente igual al tuyo, pero el objetivo del mismo es proponer una solución a tu problema original: Rellenar una matriz con números enteros aleatorios sin que estos se repitan.